# Filtro usando stream com Listas de classe que contêm listas de outras classes

Tags: java-8

Tenho a seguinte estrutura de classe

```
public class Linha implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Long id;
    private String prefixo;
    private String nome;
    private LocalDate dataInicio;
    private LocalDate dataLimite;
    private Status status;
    private List<Itinerario>  itinerarios;
    //Demais get set e metodos
}
```

```
public class Itinerario implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Long id;
    private Sentido sentido;
    private List<PontoDoItinerario> pontosDoItinerario;
    private List<Horario> hoariosDoItinerario;
    private Linha linha;
    //Demais get set e metodos
}
```

```
public class PontoDoItinerario implements Serializable,Comparable<PontoDoItinerario> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Long id;
    private Integer sequencia;
    private PontoDeParada pontoDeParada;
    private Itinerario itinerario;
    private BigDecimal km;
    private LocalTime tempoEstimado;
    //Demais get set e metodos
}
```

```
public class PontoDeParada implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Long id;
    private String prefixo;
    private String nome;
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;
    private String referencia;
    //Demais get set e metodos
}
```

Tenho uma lista de Linhas:

- Que contem uma lista de Itinerarios
- Que contem uma lista de PontoDoItinerario
- que contem um PontoDeParada por item

Necessito fazer um filtro pelo id do PontoDeParada.

Como posso fazer isso utilizando o stream.filtro do java 8?

Answer (score 1):

Um exemplo do `Stream`:

```
List<PontoDeParada> pontos = new ArrayList<>();
```

Se você quiser receber o resultado da filtragem em um `Stream` faz assim:

```
Stream<PontoDeParada> stream = pontos.stream().filter((p) ->  
{ /*aqui você faz a implementação da filtragem, que devolve um valor booleano.  
Por exemplo: return p.id > 10;  */ });
```

O problema é que o objeto `Stream` só poderá ser utilizado uma vez.
Se quiser guardar em um `ArrayList` de `PontoDeParada` pode fazer assim:

```
ArrayList<PontoDeParada> maisQ10 = new ArrayList<>();  
pontos.stream().filter( p -> p.id > 10).forEach(maisQ10.add(p));
```

Comment: Na verdade eu necessito de toda a arvore mas o filtro é no ultimo nível.
Preciso saber todas as linhas que tenham o mesmo PontoDeParada.